# docker: net: no such interface

Tags: docker

I have just installed docker on a fedora 18 system:

```
Linux draco 3.8.4-202.fc18.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 21 17:02:20 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[mike@draco docker-master]$ sudo ./docker run -i -t base /bin/bash
2013/04/02 08:24:59 net: no such interface
```

Can anyone tell me what is missing here? lxc is installed, as well as lxc-libs, and lxc-templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a network bridge configured with the name `lxcbr0`.

To do this, you can run (as root):

```
brctl addbr lxcbr0
ifconfig lxcbr0 10.65.41.1
```

Answer (score 0):

That usually means you don't have aufs setup correctly.

See https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/183 for more information.

Comment: Ok, thank you. As far as I know, there is no aufs3 for fedora18, only unionfs. I will have to see how to build aufs for kernel 3.8.

Comment: @user2236723 see this ticket, it might have some info to help you get it up and running on fedora. https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/172

Comment: I'm having the same problem, "net: no such device", but aufs is definitely loaded and listed in `/proc/filesystems`. I think the problem is related to setting up a network bridge but I'm struggling to find any documentation on that.

Comment: @KenCochrane, it seems [issue #217](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/217) is more relevant and contains more useful information.